# Copy an array to another while sorting it simultaneously

Tags: c

I have already done the sorting part and the copy but I am really struggling to put it together.
Here is only the sorting part because i am not so familiar with it. My main problem is when I start copying the array it only copies the first 2 number then stops and I think its a small problem in the for loop somewhere but i cant find it.

```
int main ()
{

    int number[30];
    int number2[30];

    int i, j, a, n;
    printf("Enter the value of N\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the numbers \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &number[i]);

   

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) 
        {
            if (number[i] < number[j]) 
            {
                a = number[i];
                number[i] = number[j];
                number[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The array is copied and sorted like:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", number[i]);
    }
    system("Pause");

}
```

Comment: ... You're never actually setting any elements of number2?

Comment: Also, you're setting the `a` value a quadratic number of times. Surely some of these are redundant?

Comment: yeah this is the sorting part standalone because when i try and merge it with the copy part it dose not work

Comment: a couple of debugging tips: 1) Use a debugger! You can step through and see where reality deviates from your expectations. 2) Until you figure it out, hardcode `n` and the array values for `number`. This will save lots of time and monotony each iteration and allow you to focus on where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled (MinGW) and ran this exact code and got the following output:

```
Enter the value of N
10
Enter the numbers
9
1
0
2
8
3
7
5
4
6
The array is copied and sorted like:
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It looks like it is correctly reverse-sorting the input values.  Note that this is a fairly common sorting algorithm (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/).

Based on this I would argue that the for loop works as is, assuming that you are looking for a reverse sort.

I am not sure what exactly is meant by "copying the array".  Array `number2` is unused and there are no operations that appear to copy the array `number`, just operations for loading it, sorting it and printing it.

Comment: Sorry for not making my point clear.I know that the sort is working i just want to copy the  array to a second array wille i am sorting it. At first i thought to just copy the first array to the second and then sort it but this is the restriction that i have. I must do it simultaneously

Comment: All you should need to do to accomplish this is to add: `number2[i] = number[i];` right after the curly brace terminating the inner for loop (`for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) `).  Each time the inner for loop completes, element `number[i]` will be the final value and will not change again.

Comment: OMG Thank you very much i  had too many hours studing and i couldn't see it. Again i am sorry for not being specific form the start